# Decode from UserDefaults is not returning any data

Tags: swift, decode, encode, userdefaults, jsondecoder

I am trying to save data from a Struct into UserDefaults and then read from it. So far the code seem to work ok with Encoding the data, but when I am trying to decode, it does not return any data.

Please find my codes listed below:

My Struct:

```
struct GameSetting: Codable {
var gameSetupText: String?
var gamePicker: Int
var groupSetupButton: Int }
```

To write to Userdefaults:

```
public let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

public let encoder = JSONEncoder()

func encodeDefault(dataModel: [GameSetting]) {
    if let encodedModel = try? encoder.encode(dataModel) {
        defaults.set(encodedModel, forKey: "encodedModel")
    }
}
```

and to Decode I used the following code:

```
   public let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    if let savedModel = defaults.value(forKey: "encodedModel") as? Data {
        
        if let decodedData = try? decoder.decode(GameSetting.self, from: savedModel) {
            print("Decoded data: \(decodedData)")
            
        }
    }
```

I have searched around in SO and other resources, but dont seem to find the answer i need. Hope you could help me and provide some advise on what to do next?

Comment: Use a do-catch statement to catch any errors thrown by the decode function. That might give you a clue.

Comment: `try?`: If an error is thrown, I don't care about it. It could have important info on why it failed, but I don't want to hear about it. So what if there was indeed an error? You might want to read it, no? So why did you used `try?` instead of `try`? So do a proper `do { try } catch { }`, and read it. Also, you are using `if let`, are you sure the test is passed? What about the `else`, like `if let ... else { print("Oops, couldn't pass the if let ...") }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your recommendation to use a Do/Catch or Try/Catch as it revealed that there was a type error in my code. I encoded an Array: [GameSetting], but decoded a dictionary GameSetting. The corrected code is here:

```
  public let decoder = JSONDecoder()

if let savedModel = defaults.value(forKey: "encodedModel") as? Data {
    
    if let decodedData = try? decoder.decode([GameSetting].self, from: savedModel) {
        print("Decoded data: \(decodedData)")
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Never use `value(forKey:)` unless you mean KVC (you don't). There is `data(forKey:)`